# Was the ancient Sith Order as secretive as the Banite Sith Order?

Tags: star-wars, sith

Darth Bane implemented the Rule of Two to limit the number of Sith to just a master and an apprentice. The two Sith would often keep their identities as Sith Lords secret.

Were the ancient Sith (before the Rule of Two) just as secretive? Or did they have no qualms about the public knowing their Sithness?

I prefer answers from canon sources, but would consider answers from other sources of lesser canon levels.

Comment: It's been a while since I've read the Bane Trilogy. But from I remember, the order of the Sith was pretty much out in the open as the Jedi before The Rule of Two. They recruited heavily for the Sith Armies to fight against the Jedi-aligned forces. The Sith homeworld was well known. But I'm not 100% sure, hence a comment not an answer.

Comment: If we go with non-canon, no they weren't as secretive, especially during the time of Revan

Comment: The correct answer is below. If you want a Legends answer, you'll need to specify what time period you want an answer from. Hundred Year Darkness? Great Hyperspace War? Great Sith War? Old Sith Empire? Revan's Sith Empire? First Jedi Purge? Second Great Galactic War? New Sith Wars? Brotherhood of Darkness? There are so many different Sith though the years that the answer would be "sometime yes, sometimes no, sometimes by accident". Anyway, @Null posted the correct Canon answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

The canon novel [*Tarkin*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)) mentions that the Sith were driven into hiding before the creation of the Republic:

> Cynosure of the Greater Seswenna sector of the Outer Rim, Eriadu could trace its history to the earliest era of the Republic. At that time, the galaxy’s dark age had ended, **the Sith had been defeated and driven into hiding**, and a true republic had emerged from the ashes. With a member of House Valorum presiding as Supreme Chancellor, a pan-galactic Senate had been created, and the military had been disbanded.
>
> <sub>**p. 31**</sub>

The Sith once ruled an [empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Empire) and fought an open war against the Jedi: the [Jedi-Sith War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi%E2%80%93Sith_war). It was after their defeat by the Jedi that Darth Bane reformed the Sith and went into hiding.

---

Legends has a much more detailed backstory for the Sith. The Sith had [multiple empires](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Empire/Legends#Legacy). The [last Sith Empire before Darth Sidious'](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Empire_(Post%E2%80%93Great_Hyperspace_War)) forced the Galactic Republic to sign the [Treaty of Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Treaty_of_Coruscant), which divided control of the galaxy between the Republic and Sith Empire:

[image: Treaty of Coruscant galactic map]

Canon has largely borrowed elements of the Legends stories.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sith were an empire before the Banite Order and did not care about such things. The Jedi and Sith fought in many wars, with many in the galaxy knowing who and what they were.